# Retrofit - 404 Not Found web api .net

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am upload an Image and a `json` data with `retrofit`:

```
{
  idCard: "100",
  idCo: "33333" 
}
```

Like bellow:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        service = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://xxx.xxx.com:000/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client).build()
                .create(Service.class);
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            android.net.Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            android.database.Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null)
                return;

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            File file = new File(filePath);
            Map<String,String> hashMaps=new HashMap<>();
            hashMaps.put("idCard","100");
            hashMaps.put("idCo","33333");
            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);

            retrofit2.Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> req = service.postImage(
                    "Bearer " + "JhNF6kFIewTuDyJSlDM3TWfmVo9DAXSa4k",
                    "application/json",
                    body,
                    hashMaps);

            req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And here is my `Service.Java`:

```
interface Service {
    String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";

    @Multipart
    @POST("api/zzz/yyy")
    Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Header(AUTH_HEADER) String authorization,
                                 @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                                 @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                 @PartMap Map<String, String> options);
}
```

But get me bellow error:

```
<-- 404 Not Found http://xxx.xxx.com:000/api/zzz/yyy (24291ms)
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2018 09:41:44 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1245
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1542274917489
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1542274930771
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<-- END HTTP (1245-byte body)
```

And my `gradle` is:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
```

Comment: I think your web service is not working.

Comment: With postMan good work.

Comment: does your server has anything in path : /api/zzz/yyy ?

Comment: remove `/` from base url and add it to `@POST("/api/zzz/yyy")`

Comment: @  Karan Mer. Not work.

Comment: did the error change?

Comment: @ Karan Mer. Not change.

Comment: your partmap must like this `@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap,`

Answer (score 0):

retrofit 2 doesn't support `/` at end of base url so remove `/` from base url and add it to `@POST("/api/zzz/yyy")`

Change your request as below

```
@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> options,
```

Assign values to map using below code and pass it with your request.

```
RequestBody idcardval= createPartFromString("100");  
RequestBody idcoval= createPartFromString("33333");  

HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();  
map.put("idCard", idcardval);  
map.put("idCo", idcoval);
```

This is function

```
private RequestBody createPartFromString (String partString) {   
   return RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, partString); 
}
```

Comment: What is createPartFromString?

Comment: Karan forgot some of his code. It's this: `private RequestBody createPartFromString (String partString) {
    return RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, partString);
}`

Comment: forgot to add function.

Comment: @PEDY are you sure you can acess this url from app? are other apis working fine?

Comment: @PEDY: it shows Authorization has been denied for this request